# How to write a function for this equation using R

Tags: r, function, parameters

`p(i,x)=a0,i+a1,icos(2π/T*x)+b1,isin(2π/T*x)+c1,ix`

Where:

`T=365`, and `a0,i`, `a1,i`, `b1,i` and `c1,i` are parameters and `x` is the only value we input.

I'm confused how to write function without when the parameters are unknown

Answer (score 1):

You just write the function for a general *i*'s

```
p_gernal <- function(x, a0, a1, b1, c1, t){
  a0 + a1 * cos(2*pi/t * x) + b1 * sin(2*pi/t * x) + c1 * x
}
```

**R** your *x,a0,a1,b1,c1* parameters should be vectors of the same length
or of lenth 1

**Example**

```
head(p_gernal(x = x, a0 = a0, a1 = a1, b1 = b1, c1 = c1, 365))
[1]  0.0000000000  0.0205558610  0.0000614598  0.0866477574  0.0137448690
```

So for a fixed index *i* it is

```
p_i <- function(x){
  p_gernal(x = x, a0 = 0, a1 = 1, b1 = 2, c1 = 3, 365)
}
> p_i(1:5)
[1]  4.034279  7.068251 10.101906 13.135235 16.168228
```

Comment: Your parameter is named `t` but you use it as `T`.